# Counting problem - How many times an inequality holds?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Let $k>2$ be a natural number and let $b$ be a non-negative real number.

Now, for each $n$, $m \in \{ 1, 2, ... k \}$, consider the following inequalities:
$$ mb < k - n $$

We have $k^2$ inequalities. How can I count the couples of $n$ and $m$ such that the inequality (for $n$ and $m$ fixed) holds?

Clearly, an algorithm would easily give an answer. But I was wondering if there is a "more-mathematical" solution.

Comment: Since the left side is at least zero and the right side is negative unless $n=k$ (in which case it is zero), the answer is never.

Comment: ops, there is an error. The right is $mb < k - n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $b$ is given.  We can note that the right side ranges from $0$ to $k-1$, so define $p=k-n \in [0,k-1]$ and ask about $mb \lt p$.  For a given $p$, the number of allowable $m$ is $\lfloor \frac {p-1}b \rfloor$  So we are asking for $\sum_{p=1}^{k-1}\lfloor \frac {p-1}b \rfloor$  Let $q=\lfloor \frac {k-2}b\rfloor$  Then $$\sum_{p=1}^{k-1}\lfloor \frac {p-1}b \rfloor=b\sum_{i=0}^{q-1}i+q(k-1-bq)=\frac{bq(q-1)}2+q(k-1-bq)$$ because the left sum starts with $b\ \ 0$'s, $b\ \ 1$'s, on to $b \ \ q-1$'s and finish with $q$'s.

Comment: Thank you! But I think that we have to consider $\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} \lfloor \frac{p}{b} \rfloor$ instead. Also, can you explain how do you write the rh-side?

Comment: @the_candyman:  since we are requiring $mb \lt p$ instead of $mb \le p$ we need the $-1$  Let $p=9, b=3$.  We can't have $m=3$ because they would be equal.  The first term of the right hand side just comes from the sum of naturals being a triangular number.

Comment: Remember that $b$ is a real number, so if we have $b=2.9$ and $p=9$, then $m=3$ is allowed and $\lfloor \frac{p-1}{b} \rfloor = 2$ doesn't work. Maybe $\lfloor \frac{p-1}{b} \rfloor + 1$ can work. For the right hand side, I don't understand the part $q(k-1-bq)$. The use of triangular number is quite intuitive but I miss the meaning of the remaining part.

Comment: @the_candyman:  I was thinking of $b$ as natural, as you can see from the last line.  You are right it gets harder with real $b$.  The last term on the right was to account for the partial run of $q$'s.  If $k=27, b=5$ you would have $5$ each of $0$ through $4$ ,the one $5$.  The parenthesized term counts how many terms are in this run, as $bq$ is the number we have already accounted for.

Comment: ok, thank you so much! I will try to reformulate the problem so that I can try other approaches to deal with $b$ as real number.

Comment: @the_candyman:  It isn't as simple with $b$ real, because you don't wind up with the nice pattern.  You can get some relief if $b$ is rational, as you will have a pattern that extends over a number of blocks.